# How can I switch user and perform multiple terminal commands as that user through a Python program

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I am working on an automation program that I want able to run this string of Linux commands in succession, then close the subprocess:
"su my_user",
"cd ~/asdf/qwer/", and
"sudo bash zxcv_zcv.sh".

I am on python 2.7 and I have tried using these commands so far:

```
subprocess.call("su my_user; cd ~/asdf/qwer/; sudo bash zxcv_zcv.sh",shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("su my_user; cd ~/asdf/qwer/; sudo bash zxcv_zcv.sh",shell=True)
os.system("su my_user; cd ~/asdf/qwer/; sudo bash zxcv_zcv.sh")
```

so far, the only thing that happens is the program creates a new terminal that I can interact with under my_user. I do not want to even see the terminal and this has not happened for any other Linux command I have run through subprocess or os. Does anyone know what is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to interact with an instance of [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). Or, just use shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found the answer to this question for anyone wondering. For the string of commands I used, just add a -c between "su" and "my_user" and it will run fine.

```
subprocess.call("su -c my_user; cd ~/asdf/qwer/; sudo bash zxcv_zcv.sh", shell=True)
```